# How to use temporary tables right in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to use temporary table to simplify my query but I am getting an error message.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.name
INTO #TmpEmplyee
FROM Employee E, Outsourcing O, Student S
WHERE E.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Student UNION SELECT ID FROM Outsourcing)

SELECT R.name, I.startDate, T.name
FROM Role R, Inn I, #TmpEmplyee T
WHERE I.name = R.name AND I.ID = T.id
```

And the error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Employee E, Outsourcing O, Student S WHERE E.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Stud' at line 3
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html   mysql doesn't support `select ... into`. it has `insert .. select from`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a temporary table from a select you should use this syntax

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytemptable 
SELECT Field1, Field2 
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 1):

in mysql you need to create you temp table before your query. also you do not need Outsourcing O, Student S in the FROM since you are not selecting from them:

```
INSERT INTO #TmpEmplyee
SELECT E.ID, E.name
FROM Employee E
WHERE E.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Student UNION SELECT ID FROM Outsourcing)
```

Answer (score 1):

give this a try,

```
SELECT R.name, I.startDate, T.name
FROM    Role R 
        INNER JOIN Inn I
            ON I.name = R.name
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT E.ID, E.name
            -- remember that the join below produces CROSS JOIN
            FROM Employee E, Outsourcing O, Student S
            WHERE E.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID FROM Student 
                                UNION 
                                SELECT ID FROM Outsourcing)
        ) T ON I.ID = T.id
```